# Avoid the `default` object when exporting a Node module for the browser with Webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, export

I'm sure this is simple but it's confounding me! I maintain a few NPM modules for browser convenience functions which work just fine when a parent app uses `require` or `import` and then bundles them with Webpack. But, in deference to the myriad user environments out there, I'd like to provide a standalone bundle in a `dist` directory in Github for those who need to include it in a `<script>` tag.

The problem, in short, is that when I use Webpack to make a browser-ready module, [per the Webpack instructions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/), the object exposed to `window` is always a `Module` that has a single property, `default`, that contains the function itself.

For example, my [`elastic-svg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elastic-svg), which is a super-simple tool to make SVGs resize like `div`s and intelligently resize the contents, exports like so:

`export default function elasticSVG(selector, opts) {` [source](https://github.com/TimeMagazine/elastic-svg/blob/master/index.js#L3)

The Webpack config, which I keep outside the module so as not to muddy the source, looks like this:

```
{
  entry: './index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "./dist"),
    filename: 'elasticSVG.js',
    library: 'elasticSVG',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  // relevant modules and rules etc.
```

This is all fine and good, but when I test the file in [`dist/elasticSVG.js`](https://github.com/TimeMagazine/elastic-svg/blob/master/dist/elasticSVG.js) from [examples/demo.html](https://github.com/TimeMagazine/elastic-svg/blob/master/examples/demo.html), I see this:

[image]

Surely there's a simple way to export the module such like, like a normal, old-fashioned module, `window.elasticSVG` is the function itself? This may solve another issue I don't under, which is why this **does** work in Node:

```
import elasticSVG from 'elastic-svg';
```

but this **doesn't** work:

```
import * as elasticSVG from 'elastic-svg';
```

Not a big problem, but I'd like to understand why. It's difficult to Google since the environment changes so rapidly! I've tried a variety of other `export` syntaxes without much success. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

This is multiple questions packed into one question,

First why did this work

```
import elasticSVG from 'elastic-svg';
```

while this did not work

```
import * as elasticSVG from 'elastic-svg';
```

is because you are exporting a default export, a default export can be imported by any name so, the following will also work

```
import elasticSVGMYSepcialName from 'elastic-svg';
```

on the other hand

```
import * as elasticSVG from 'elastic-svg';
```

means import all named exports from this module under the name elasticSVG, in your case you are not exporting any named variable, so this wont work.

Now if you wish for webpack to directly inject your function into the window, you need to add libraryExport to your output object in webpack

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), "./dist"),
    filename: 'elasticSVG.js',
    library: 'elasticSVG',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    libraryExport: "default"
  },
```

[libraryExport](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibraryexport) will configure which module will be exposed by Your library (elasticSVG) from your entry point module/namespace ( your ./index.js file).

Comment: libraryExport: "default" was the answer for me.